# How to input several time-series to LSTM in keras

Tags: python, keras, classification, lstm

I have about 1000 nodes dataset where each node has 4 time-series. Each time series is exactly 6 length long.The label is `0` or `1` (i.e. binary classification).

More precisely my dataset looks as follows.

```
node, time-series1, time_series2, time_series_3, time_series4, Label
n1, [1.2, 2.5, 3.7, 4.2, 5.6, 8.8], [6.2, 5.5, 4.7, 3.2, 2.6, 1.8], …, 1
n2, [5.2, 4.5, 3.7, 2.2, 1.6, 0.8], [8.2, 7.5, 6.7, 5.2, 4.6, 1.8], …, 0
and so on.
```

Since, I have time-series, I assumed that it is more like **sequence classification** where most of the blog posts have used LSTM. I have never worked with LSTMs before and this is going to be my first ever keras application. So, I started working with the most basic `sequential LSTM` template as follows.

```
# create the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(5000, 32, input_length=24))
model.add(LSTM(100))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())
```

However, I am having difficulties in understanding how I can input four time-series to LSTM using the `embedding` layer. Can I use four `embedding` layers or are there any other way to resolve this issue?

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways you could structure this. For starters I would probably just flatten the 4 series into an array of 24 numbers and use Dense layers

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32, input_shape=24))
model.add(Dense(32))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

print(data.shape) # (1000, 24)
model.fit(data, target)
```

You could have 4 separate inputs that process 4 series individually with `LSTM` layers. But you'd need to use the functional API. e.g.

```
input1 = Input(shape=(6,1))
x1 = LSTM(10)(input1)
input2 = Input(shape=(6,1))
x2 = LSTM(10)(input2)
input3 = Input(shape=(6,1))
x3 = LSTM(10)(input3)
input4 = Input(shape=(6,1))
x4 = LSTM(10)(input4)

x = concatenate([x1,x2,x3,x4])
x = Drouput(0.2)(x)
x = Dense(40)(x)
x = Drouput(0.2)(x)
output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)

model = Model(inputs=[input1,input2,input3,input4], outputs=output)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

print(data1.shape) #(1000,6,1)
model.fit([data1,data2,data3,data4], target)
```

Or if your data is in the shape `(1000, 6, 4)` you could use one LSTM and treat each series as a separate feature

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(10, input_shape=(6,4)))
model.add(Dense(32))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

print(data.shape) # (1000, 6, 4)
model.fit(data, target)
```

Or you could use a CNN instead of an RNN.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(10, kernel_size=3, input_shape=(6,4)))
model.add(Conv1D(10, kernel_size=2))
model.add(GlobalMaxPooling1D())
model.add(Dense(10))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

print(data.shape) # (1000, 6, 4)
model.fit(data, target)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the amazing answer. This is exactly what I was looking for. I really like your suggestion of using `functional` api. By the way do you think my data size is small (i.e. considering only 1000 nodes) for a initial start? My other question is can we have `dropout` layers in the functional api model? If so how? :)

Comment: I added a couple dropout layers to the second example. Also I realized it didn't have the output layer. Yeah it might not be enough data. Depends on the problem but I think first and last examples that don't use LSTM are more likely to succeed with less data.

Comment: Also note that if you are using the functional example each number in a series needs to be wrapped in it's own array. e.g. `[[1.2], [2.5], [3.7], [4.2], [5.6], [8.8]]` because LSTMs expect a series of 1D vectors

Comment: thanks a lot for the valuable details. I will run the models during the weekend and will let you know if I faced any issues. Thanks a lot once again :)

Answer (score 2):

You can treat each sequence within each node as a separate channel. So, first of all reshape your data into n_samples (I think you are calling this nodes), n_steps, and n_channel. With the data set you have, `n_steps=6` and `n_channel=4`. Basically you are stacking your different time series data per each sample (node).

Then, you can create you LSTM model. Something like this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(64, input_shape=(6, 4), activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())
```

Note that you can have different activations with LSTM and may not necessarily need a Dense layer. But a Dense layer is an additional nonlinear layer and might improve the performance.

You can also stack LSTM layers to get more complex models like this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(64, input_shape=(6, 4), return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(1, input_shape=(6, 4)))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())
```